# Firebase validate a zip code

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I tried the following regular expression

```
newData.val().matches(/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/)
```

I get an error that the escape character `\d` isn't recognized. I removed and cleared the errors but I still get a permission denied error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use double slashes `\\`.

It will look like

```
newData.val().matches(/(^\\d{5}$)|(^\\d{5}-\\d{4}$)/)
```

Take some time observing some of the examples that you can find on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex#supported_features).